# Delay by 1 microsecond in C MIPS Environment

Tags: c, mips, clock, u8glib

I'm trying to port u8glib (graphics library) to MIPS processor, OpenWrt router.
Here's an [example](https://code.google.com/p/u8glib/source/browse/sys/arm/lpc1114/common/u8g_arm.c) in arm environment.

As such, one of the routines I must implement is:

```
delay_micro_seconds(uint32_t us)
```

Since this is a high resolution unit of time, how can I do this reliably in my environment? I've tried the following, but I'm not even sure how to validate it:

```
nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0, 1000}}, NULL);
```

**How can I validate this approach? If its a  bad approach, how could I reliably delay by 1 microsecond in C?**

EDIT: I've tried this, but I'm getting strange output, I expect the difference between the two print s to be 1000*10 iterations = 10,000 , but it is actually closer to 670,000 nanoseconds:

```
   int main(int argc, char **argv)
   {
    long res, resb;
    struct timespec ts, tsb;
    int i;

    res = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0,1000}}, NULL);
    }

    resb = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tsb);

    if (0 == res) printf("%ld %ld\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
    else perror("clock_gettime");
    if (0 == resb) printf("%ld %ld\n", tsb.tv_sec, tsb.tv_nsec);
    else perror("clock_gettime"); //getting 670k delta instead of 10k for tv_nsec
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you have these kind of tight real-time requirements, it doesn't make any sense whatsoever to 1) use any OS which is not a RTOS and 2) use stdio.

Comment: Turns out that it's not that important to get exact delay X, but rather at least X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your codes would run under Linux.

First, using `clock_getres(2)` to find a clock's resolution.
and then, using `clock_nanosleep(2)` might make more accurate sleep.

To validate the sleep, I suggest you check elapsed time with `clock_gettime(2)`

```
res = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
if (0 == res) printf("%ld %ld\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
else perror("clock_gettime");

clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, &delay, NULL);

res = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
if (0 == res) printf("%ld %ld\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
else perror("clock_gettime");
```

Also, if necessary, you can recompile your kernel with higher HZ configuration.
It would be helpful to read time(7) man page. Especially, **The software clock, HZ, and jiffies** and **High-resolution timers** sections.
Though my man pages says that High-resolution timer is not supported under mips architecture but I just googled it and mips-linux support HRT apparently.

Comment: Not sure about MIPS, but on some of my other lesser embedded platforms, sometime the system clock was artificially inflated beyond 1 microsecond resolution in order to make sure the clock never returned the same value twice. Trying to use the clock to measure time gaps nearly the same width as its resolution might be misleading. Better to call `clock_nanosleep(*xxx*)` 10 times in a row, that way you can be sure the `clock_gettime` calls have several 'true ticks' between them.

Answer (score 1):

Is this sleep synchronous? (I'm not familiar with your platform)

## Validation

- If you have development tools available, are there any profiling tools included? They can at least help you measure execution time.
- You can also loop around your *sleep* call 1000+ times in a test program. Before you enter the loop, get a timestamp from the system clock. After the loop is done cycling, take another timestamp and compare with the first. Remember the loop itself will have some time overhead, but otherwise this will let you know how accurate (overshoot or undershoot) your *sleep* is. (If you cycle 1,000,000 time around a 1 microsecond sleep function, you would expect that it finishes quite near to 1 second.

## Alternative

Sleep functions are not always **perfect** to their resolution, but they promise to be simple to use and always get you in the neighborhood of what they say. There are many statements that run much quicker than a microsecond, `a++;`.

- Using a similar method as above, you could easily make a homemade synchronous timer with awesome accuracy using a FOR loop with some pointless statement inside of it. Once you find out how many iterations lands you nearest 1 microsecond, it should never change and you could hardcode a function out of it.

If you intend your delay to be asynchronous with a multi-tasking process in mind, this obviously would not cooperate with the other tasks well.

Comment: In multi-tasking environment you can't know how long some loop will take. It will vary, depending on system load, priorities of other tasks, etc.

Comment: I see, so this sleep IS intended to be Asyncronous?

Comment: As far as I understand it, it's user code running under OpenWRT (linux), so OS may switch context while your loop is executing.